# Error en un programa básico en Java

Tags: java

Hola estoy aprendiendo Java y tengo un problema en un ejercicio básico, no sé si es por sintaxis o por que es, el enunciado es el siguiente

Hacer un programa que imprima por pantalla "Escribe 's' para salir o 'c' para continuar en el bucle". Después se nos pedirá que introduzcamos por teclado una letra. Si es una 's' entonces saldremos del bucle, si es una 'c' se escribirá por pantalla "sigues en el bucle".

```
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Punto_13_Pagina_65 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letra;
        letra = "c";
        while (letra == "c") {

            System.out.println("Escribe 's' para salir o 'c' para continuar en el bucle");
            letra = scanner.nextLine();
            if (letra == "c") {
                System.out.println("Sigues en el bucle");
            } else if (letra == "s") {
                System.out.println("Saliste del bucle");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ey sali del ciclo");
    }

}
```

Creería que el error está en la linea 15 (letra = scanner.nextLine();) y que no es el mismo tipo de variable o algo así, muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas esta un poco mal explicado pero creo que te entiendo, espero que sea eso lo que intentas!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=  new Scanner(System.in);
        String letra= "c";
        String letra2 ="s";
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {

            System.out.println("Escribe 's' para salir o 'c' para continuar en el bucle");
            letra = scan.nextLine();
            if (letra.equals(letra)) {
                System.out.println("Sigues en el bucle");
                exit=false;
            } 

            if (letra.equals(letra2)) {
                System.out.println("Saliste del bucle");
               exit=true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ey sali del ciclo");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas el comparador **==** , es para comparar cifras numéricas.

En el caso de las variables de tipo String en este caso, es conveniente usar el método

```
.equalsIgnoreCase("c")
```

El cual se encarga de comparar dos String, ignorando si es que alguno de los dos String tiene letras en Mayúsculas o Minúsculas en comparación con el segundo String

También por otro lado, he notado que tienes el siguiente mensaje dentro de tu ciclo `WHILE`

```
System.out.println("Ey sali del ciclo");
```

Esto produce que aunque sigas en el bucle este mensaje aparezca igual, por lo mismo, lo he sacado del bucle `WHILE`

Con todo lo dicho anteriormente tu código quedaría, más o menos, de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner;
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String letra;
           letra = "c";
            while (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {

                    System.out.println("Escribe 's' para salir o 'c' para continuar en el bucle");
                    letra = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(letra);



                    if (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("c") ) {
                                System.out.println("Sigues en el bucle");

                    } else {
                                System.out.println("Saliste del bucle");
                                break;

                     }



            }

            System.out.println("Ey sali del ciclo");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letra;
        letra = "";
        System.out.println("Escribe 's' para salir o 'c' para continuar en el bucle");
        letra = scanner.nextLine();
        do {            
            if (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                System.out.println("Saliste del bucle");
                break;
            }
                System.out.println("Sigues en el bucle");
                letra = scanner.nextLine();

        }while (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("c") || !letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
        System.out.println("Saliste del bucle");
```

Un Do-While en el que se confirme dos condiciones: que sea igual a "c" y distinto de "s"
Saludos!